# event.target and Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have an application that can trigger javascript functions on different events (like onBlur). The function simply got the id and an attribute _id for the element that triggered the event. For Chrome, event.target has suddenly stopped working and I suspect it has something to do with a recent change in Chrome:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dcfa1803d4408370e3b1a187b84d4a6b620f491a

```
onBlur__Invalid : function () {
    // For Internet Explorer
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1) {
        var currentId = window.event.srcElement.getAttribute('_id');
        var currentTarget =  '#' + window.event.srcElement.id;
    }
    // For other browsers
    else {
        var currentId = event.target.getAttribute('_id');
        var currentTarget = '#' + event.target.id;
    }
    // Show Hint-message if x-form-invalid
    if (currentId.indexOf("date_") > -1 && $(currentTarget).hasClass('x-form-invalid')) {
        $(currentTarget).parents().eq(5).next().addClass('is_invalid');
    }
    else {
        $(currentTarget).parents().eq(5).next().removeClass('is_invalid');
    }
    if($(currentTarget).hasClass('x-form-invalid')) {
        $(currentTarget).parent().next().addClass('is_invalid');
    }
    else {
        $(currentTarget).parent().next().removeClass('is_invalid');
    }
},
```

Do anyone know an alterantive to event.target that works with Chrome and this script, or see a reason for this script to simply stop working overnight? As soon as the script enters the else statement it fails and stops running. Adding a try/catch gives the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Edit:
If I pass the attribute _id from the onBlur function call like this:

```
ca_fd.js.onBlur__Invalid("sel_1");
```

I have managed to get it working like this:

```
onBlur__Invalid : function (e) {
    // Show Hint-message if x-form-invalid
    var currentTarget= '\'input[_id="' + e + '"]\''
    alert($(currentTarget).attr('id'));
    if (e.indexOf("date_") > -1 && $(currentTarget).hasClass('x-form-invalid')) {
        $(currentTarget).parents().eq(5).next().addClass('is_invalid');
    }
    else {
        $(currentTarget).parents().eq(5).next().removeClass('is_invalid');
    }
    if($(currentTarget).hasClass('x-form-invalid')) {
        $(currentTarget).parent().next().addClass('is_invalid');
    }
    else {
        $(currentTarget).parent().next().removeClass('is_invalid');
    }
},
```

The call used to be ca_fd.js.onBlur__Invalid();, so this means I have to add the _id manually in all elements in all forms in the form designer of the application. The alert will in this case return "x-auto-16".

Hopefully the application can pass the _id I need with a variable, but I have yet to find it. Adding event or _id just returns undefined.

Comment: Are you sure the handler is accepting an `event` parameter?

Comment: I must admit I'm not that skilled in this field. All I know is that the function has been working for a long time, but recently doesn't do what it used too. The application itself has not been updated, the if satement still works for IE, so I assumed Chrome which auto updates regulary had something to do with it.

Comment: To start with, look at your function. Does it accept an `event` parameter? `window.event` [should not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

Comment: The way I read the try/catch error is that event is undefined. The if statement with windows.event only fires when using Internet Explorer. Event should be a built-in property, no? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp

Comment: Again, *please look at your function* - post it in your question body so we can all see whether it uses an `event` parameter or not. w3schools is notoriously not-so-reliable - if you're just learning JS, probably better to rely on MDN

Comment: Added the whole function. It's simply called by the call onBlur__DSS_Invalid(); on the onBlur event of form-elements in the applications form designer.

Comment: Thanks, yep, looks like that's the problem, probably - you're missing the `event` parameter, which all handlers using events should have. (can't be 100% sure since we aren't seeing where `onBlur__DSS_Invalid `'s being referenced later, but it seems pretty likely it's being passed to an `addEventListener`?)

Comment: This was working yesterday. Chrome was updated at the end of my workday yesterday. I still believe the link I provide is the culprit. We might have used event.target wrong and it just happened to work the way we wanted. We could pass the _id to the function, but we have to get the id attribute which contains a random number in terms of its placement in the form. Example of inpiut field:
<input type="text" class=" x-form-field x-form-text  x-form-invalid " id="x-auto-9-input" tabindex="0" name="random" _id="txtf_1" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="x-auto-20" style="width: 774px;">